AI enhanced search doesn't understand voting rules
There's an upvote button in the AI-enhanced search, which upvotes all questions and answers used for the content. That works, but you see the green banner "Thanks for upvoting this content!" also when

you have already upvoted the posts
you wrote the posts
the posts are locked
you are not logged in

or a combination of the above and there's no way any of the votes could have succeeded.


Does it ever successfully upvote the posts?

Yes, I checked my voting history and saw some new votes.

I wonder if you can exceed the daily vote limit this way.

wait what, who thought this was okay

Closing this one as I've answered the more direct question of "was the test officially announced". But yeah, should've never happened :)
